# How to let my menu items on the same line as my logo?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am starting using Bootstrap 3 and for my nav bar, I have a logo about 100px in height. The items are on the right, with a margin-top on the ul (to vertically center my menu item).

My issue is that when the screen is not big enough, ALL menu item starts under the logo and I'd like to have as many menu item as I can on the same line as the logo.

Here is a JS Bin to try to illustrate my issue : 
http://jsbin.com/posigasile/2/edit?html,css,output

Here is a better illustration (from my working directory). The second image is what I have when the screen is big enough and the first image is what happens when the screen is smaller : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQjrL.jpg

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution i found, not the most tidy one, but works.

so the trick is you divide the ul in to blocks to many ul.
when you keep just ul , it is treated as one block of code and so when you decrease the screen size, the whole blocks switchs to next line.

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li></ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>

</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>

</ul><ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>

</ul><ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>

</ul>

      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi ! Thank you very much for this answer, this is what I was looking for. Even if it's not very clean, it'll do the trick ! Thanks !